# magento homepage shows error after recreating database with the same name

Tags: mysql, database, magento

This is what happened...

I first backup the database file associate with a Magento site. Then I deleted the whole database and re-created the other one with the same title. I imported the .sql file back in, assign the same user to it.

Website works fine except loading the homepage (www.domain.com/index.php) it flashes the error code as image shows below and quickly returns a 404 not found page.

[image]

How can I fix this, your time is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't look like you copied the whole database the first time. You possibly missed the core_resource table, and Magento may be trying to recreate the core tables again. If your stack trace originates at a `Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup` class, this would explain it

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the default web URL is set to CMS. This is a common issue when migrating from Magento v1.x to Magento 2.

Stores > Configuration > Web > Default Pages > Default Web URL 
Default Web URL = cms

Then set your CMS Home Page and clean the cache.